# Azure DevOps The code coverage value (0%, 0 lines) is lower than the minimum value

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Azure Devops pipeline started failing on self hosted agent on Check build quality task

```
steps:
- task: mspremier.BuildQualityChecks.QualityChecks-task.BuildQualityChecks@6
  displayName: 'Check build quality'
  inputs:
    checkCoverage: true
    coverageFailOption: fixed
    coverageType: lines
    coverageThreshold: 50
    buildPlatform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
  enabled: false
  timeoutInMinutes: 24
```

Tried with all the task versions
Tried all the coverage types and added timeout minutes too but It's not working

I tried on Microsoft hosted agent win 2019 and It worked
, Till last week it was working on self hosted 2019 agent

Happy to provide more information if needed

Also I would like to understand if we are already doing sonar code scan does this task adds any value ?

Answer (score 2):

If you're running this check on a PR without any code changes, ie. only adding this build check. By default the code coverage check will fail as theres no additional coverage added.

Have a look atthe `treat0of0as100` option listed here https://github.com/MicrosoftPremier/VstsExtensions/blob/master/BuildQualityChecks/en-US/overview.md.